# Long LINQ to SQL query execution after several executions

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have weird problem that I cannot solve. I have an ASP.NET MVC Core 2 application using EF Core. I have a button that triggers an action method. I click the button, it redirects me to the view where I click another button, that makes some database operations and brings me back to the original page.

And inside that method I simply use my `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
MyEntry myEntry = _db.MyEntries.FirstOrDefault(e => e.MyProperty == myValue);
```

The thing is that when I go that path several times, it works. And it stops working on the eighth call, it's always the same line (executing database) that suddenly starts taking about half a minute.

When I modify my code (e.g. move some database code outside loop, create collection and then use it inside loop) it stops working at the other moment - always the same line of code, after the same number of executions, but in a different place.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

I simply use the database in my controller:

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _database;

public MyController(ApplicationDbContext database)
{
   _database = database;
}
```

And `ApplicationDbContext` is:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `When I modify my code (e.g. move some database code outside loop, create collection and then use it inside loop) it stops working at the other moment `. Share us complete demo to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like the MyEntry entity needs a key:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntry>()
        .HasKey(b => new { b.Id, b.MyProperty});
}
```